# Is there a triangle representation for the Canadian airspace?

Tags: airspace, canada

I'm looking for the following figure, except modified for Canadian airspace.
Does anybody have a copy, or can help me modify this one? I searched everywhere and could not find one.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

How about this? I made it, so feel free to correct errors. I could never remember them either and the FAA triangle is amazing. I corrected the earlier triangle with a TCCA doc, and simplified.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a triangle representation, but this poster summarise the particularities of the Canadian airspace

https://tc.canada.ca/sites/default/files/migrated/tc_6010_airspaceposter_e.pdf

Comment: The link has expired.  Can you post the contents of that page please?

Comment: The link is updated @wbeard52